# Recursively iterate a nested dictionary and adding it to a TreeViewItem Heirarchy not working as intended

Tags: c#, wpf, parsing, dictionary, recursion

Here's a little background of my issue - I have a WPF application containing a TreeView control, which I plan to populate using a nested dictionary of TFS Branch Paths, However, The parent of the innermost Child node is misbehaving and is empty. This is all done as a little exercise to see if I can universalize everyone's environment using a little application, and can probably already be done using powershell.

[image: Project Heirarchy]

A little foreground on code - I am trying to refactor this to also be as functional as possible, and probably did a few bad things such as creating a Extended method for a foreach loop, but this is not the issue here - the issue is the empty node as indicated above.

Let's jump in:

Code to get Project Hierarchy from TFS:

```
        private static Result<BranchProviderValueObject> GetBranchProviders()
        {
            if (!Settings.Default.TfsUri.IsWellFormedOriginalString())
            {
                UniversalErrorHandler.Error("URI in settings is not well formed.");
            }

            return BranchProviderValueObject.Create(Settings.Default.TfsUri
                .TryMap(TfsConfigurationServerFactory.GetConfigurationServer)
                .TryMap(configurationServer =>
                {
                    return configurationServer.CatalogNode.QueryChildren(new[] { CatalogResourceTypes.ProjectCollection }, false, CatalogQueryOptions.None)
                        .ForEach(node =>
                        {
                            return new Guid(node.Resource.Properties["InstanceId"])
                                .TryMap(configurationServer.GetTeamProjectCollection)
                                .TryMap(projectCollection => projectCollection.GetService<VersionControlServer>().QueryRootBranchObjects(RecursionType.Full));
                        }).Aggregate((current, list) => current.ToArray());
                }))
                .OnFailure(failedResult => BranchProviderValueObject.Create(new List<BranchObject>()));
        }

        public static List<string> GetBranchHierarchy()
        {
            return GetBranchProviders()
                .Value //Value from result
                .Value //Value from Value Object
                .Select(branchObjectName => branchObjectName.Properties.RootItem.Item).ToList();
        }
```

**Result**
When `GetBranchHierachy()` is called, it returns a list of strings

```
Count = 14
    [0]: "$/CitadelFoundation/Main/MAIN"
    [1]: "$/CitadelFoundation/Main/DEV-Eon"
    [2]: "$/CitadelFoundation/Main/DEV-Greg"
    [3]: "$/CitadelFoundation/Main/DEV-Jim"
    [4]: "$/CitadelFoundation/Main/DEV"
    [5]: "$/CitadelFoundation/Main/PROD"
    [6]: "$/CitadelFoundation/Main/DESIGN"
    [7]: "$/CitadelFoundation/Main/DEV-Temp"
    [8]: "$/CitadelFoundation/Main/EDGE"
    [9]: "$/CitadelFoundation/Main/Eon"
    [10]: "$/CitadelFoundation/Main/Interim"
    [11]: "$/CitadelFoundation/Main/LostAndFound"
    [12]: "$/CitadelFoundation/Main/MOAT"
    [13]: "$/CitadelFoundation/Main/TEMP"
```

Parsing the list into an Nested Dictionary:

The dictionary is represented in a similar manner to a File Hierarchy

The Code (not refactored, but verified the hierarchy gets constructed correctly):

```
    public Dictionary<string, DictionaryParserTreeview> Nodes = new Dictionary<string, DictionaryParserTreeview>();
    private string Item { get; set; }

    public void AddItems(string path)
    {
        var current = this;
        var parts = path.Split(new[] { '/' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

        foreach (var part in parts)
        {
            DictionaryParserTreeview child;
            if (!current.Nodes.TryGetValue(part, out child))
            {
                child = new DictionaryParserTreeview
                {
                    Item = part
                };

                current.Nodes[part] = child;
            }
            current = child;
        }
    }
```

[image: Representation of nested Dictionary]

That's enough background - now to get to the issue as with first Screenshot:

I am iterating this dictionary and parsing it into a WPF TreeViewItem object using a recursive method, and the output is slightly incorrect as you saw in the first screenshot, **what can I do to resolve this issue?**

```
    private void PopulateBranchesIntoUi()
    {
        var parser = new DictionaryParserTreeview();
        BranchProvider.GetBranchHierarchy().ForEach(parser.AddItems);
        projectHeirarchyTreeview.Items.Add(BuildTreeViewItems(parser.Nodes));

    }

    private TreeViewItem BuildTreeViewItems(Dictionary<string, DictionaryParserTreeview> nodes)
    {
        var item = new TreeViewItem();

        foreach (var node in nodes)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(node.Key);
            if (node.Value.Nodes.Count == 0)
            {
                item.Items.Add(node.Key);
            }
            else
            {
                item.Header = node.Key;
                item.Items.Add(BuildTreeViewItems(node.Value.Nodes));
            }
        }
        return item;
    }
```

Comment: To be honest- this became even more complicated to explain than to do ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, the problem is, that you add an extra item when `(node.Value.Nodes.Count == 0)`. This `var item = new TreeViewItem();` will create a new item, but when `(node.Value.Nodes.Count == 0)` the `Header` property is never assigned.

```
private TreeViewItem BuildTreeViewItems(Dictionary<string, DictionaryParserTreeview> nodes)
{
    var item = new TreeViewItem();

    foreach (var node in nodes)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(node.Key);
        if (node.Value.Nodes.Count == 0)
        {
            // item.Items.Add(node.Key);  <-- don't add a new item.
            item.Header = node.Key; // just assign the header here.
        }
        else
        {
            item.Header = node.Key;
            item.Items.Add(BuildTreeViewItems(node.Value.Nodes));
        }
    }
    return item;
}
```

---

UPDATE:

I would pass the parent node, instead of creating a parent in the method, change it like this:   *(untested, written on website)*

```
private void PopulateBranchesIntoUi()
{
    var rootNode = new TreeViewItem { Header = "$" };

    BuildTreeViewItems(rootNode, parser.Nodes);

    projectHeirarchyTreeview.Items.Add(rootNode);
}


private void BuildTreeViewItems(TreeViewItem parent, Dictionary<string, DictionaryParserTreeview> nodes)
{
    foreach (var node in nodes)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(node.Key);

        var item = new TreeViewItem { Header = node.Key };

        BuildTreeViewItems(item, node.Value.Nodes);

        parent.Items.Add(item);
    }
}
```

---

Probably a half-solution:

```
private void PopulateBranchesIntoUi()
{
    var firstNode = parser.Nodes.First();

    var rootNode = new TreeViewItem { Header = firstNode.Key };

    BuildTreeViewItems(rootNode, firstNode.Nodes);

    projectHeirarchyTreeview.Items.Add(rootNode);
}
```

Comment: hmm There seems to be a caveat now - it only adds the last item of the innermost dictionary. 

https://gyazo.com/c36a3c053885e99fa64b0a5cea9db832

Comment: I'm still checking the code, i think there is something wrong. I'll update it.

Comment: The problem is, that you return 1 node, but pass multiple nodes into the method.

Comment: That's almost perfect. It made the root node, and seems like a duplicate thereof as a child. https://gyazo.com/354b17d855cc4bb74bd7f41a233a360d

Comment: I am marking your question as answer. I found a way to cheat it - I will list the TFS Url as the "Root node Header". Thank you so much!

https://gyazo.com/8369574ceac89a5fb181f43aac7450e9